# Convergence of sequence of function in $C[0, 1]$ and $C^1[0, 1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity

I try to prove that the sequence $\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-\frac{t^{n+2}}{n+2}$ is convergent in $C[0, 1]$ but not convergent in $C^1[0, 1]$ where $C^1$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions.

I try to show that the it is in fact a cauchy sequence, then I lost in the middle.

Is there any way to that it is not cauchy in  the space of continuously differentiable function.

Comment: What norms are you using?

Comment: I am using supremum norm.

Comment: You are using the supremum norm on $C^1?$

Comment: Or are you using $||f||_\infty$ for $C$ and $||f||_\infty+||f'||_\infty$ for $C^1$?

Comment: Yes sranthrop i am using same norm you described . Thank you

Comment: Ok, but then the sequence converges in $C$ as well as in $C^1$...

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $f_n(t)=t^{n+1}/(n+1)-t^{n+2}/(n+2)$ actually converges to $0$ in $C^1.$ The $\sup$ norm estimate on $f_n$ is easy:

$$\|f_n-0\|_\infty = \|f_n\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{n+1}+ \frac{1}{n+2} \to 0.$$

Now $f_n'(t)= t^n - t^{n+1} = t^n(1-t).$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ We have

$$\sup_{[1-\epsilon,1]} |f_n'| \le 1\cdot\epsilon= \epsilon.$$

We also have

$$\sup_{[0,1-\epsilon]} |f_n'| \le (1-\epsilon)^n\cdot 1.$$

Thus $\sup_{[0,1]} |f_n'| \le \max(\epsilon,(1-\epsilon)^n).$ Because $(1-\epsilon)^n\to 0,$ $\max (\epsilon,(1-\epsilon)^n) = \epsilon$ for large $n,$ and we're done.